# GCP Cloud function closes before update writes to firestore

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**-- EDIT --**

For people seeing this for the first time these are the approaches I have tried with no changes to the issue

- wrapping code in a `try catch` - no errors caught
- return the `.update` instead of `await`
- using `.then()` syntax instead of `async await`
- return a value (`null`) explicitly efter the last `.update()` in `savePDF`

only working solution so far with a cloud function is to delay the success response for a given time like this.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  res.status(200).send('Requisition sent and saved')
})
```

**--**

I have a cloud function which is call from the client in order to do some data manipulation and creation.

Everything works as intended however I can't circumvent an recurring and sometimes periodic issue. (Though I have a strong feeling that cold start also plays a part)

**The issue:**

The second (last) `await docRef.update({ ... })` in `savePDF` finishes and I can log the returned writeTimestamp data. However the firestore database is never updated with the new data.
If I wrap the `res.status(200).send('Requisition sent and saved')` in a `setTimeout` with e.g. 1000ms the firebase data will be updated with the correct data provided by the last `await docRef.update({ ... })` in `savePDF`.

**The Question:**

Can any of you guys enlighten me? everything works as inteded except for the above mentioned hiccup

**The Code (scraped of unneeded content):**

```js
    const admin = require('firebase-admin')
    const functions = require('firebase-functions')
    const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })
    const { config, isProd } = require('../../utils/config')
    const { convertHTMLToPDF } = require('../../utils/convertHTMLToPDF')
    
    let sendEmail = null
    
    // if app already initialized with admin, use that one else setup new app
    admin.apps.length
      ? admin.app()
      : admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(config.serviceAccount),
      })
    
    exports.createAndSendPDF = functions.runWith({
      memory: '2GB',
    }).region('europe-west3').https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      cors(req, res, async () => {
    
        // 1. Build file path
        const storagePathRef = 'path/to/location/file.pdf'
    
        // 2. Open bucket connection
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(config.storage)
    
        const fileRef = bucket.file(storagePathRef)
        // conversion of HTML document to PDF with puppeteer (works as intended)
        const pdf = await convertHTMLToPDF(htmlDocument)
        
        // Must be completed before termination of cloud function
        await Promise.all([
          savePDF({ storagePathRef, fileRef }, pdf),
          sendPDF(pdf)
        ])
    
        res.status(200).send('Requisition sent and saved')
      })
    })
    
    const savePDF = async (refs, pdf) => {
      const {
        storagePathRef,
        fileRef,
      } = refs
    
      // Prop meta object
      const initialPDFData = { /* just meta data */}
    
      // Create meta data for firestore
      const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('MyCollection').doc('DocID')
      const docData = (await docRef.get()).data()
      const existingPDFs = docData.pdfs || []
      
      // Update field with new array
      const initialMetaUpdatePromise = docRef.update({
        pdfs: [...existingPDFs, initialPDFData],
      })
    
      // Save PDF
      const fileSavePromise = fileRef.save(pdf, { resumable: false })
    
      // Wait for initial meta update and file save to be done
      await Promise.all([
        initialMetaUpdatePromise,
        fileSavePromise
      ])
    
      // Get existing file meta
      const { name, size, contentType } = (await fileRef.getMetadata())[0]
    
      // Update meta object
      const updatedProMeta = {
        ...initialPDFData,
        name: name.split('/').slice(-1)[0],
        size: Number(size) || -1,
        type: contentType,
        status: 'generated',
      }
    
      // Update requisition files list
      await docRef.update({
        requisitionFiles: [...existingPDFs, updatedProMeta],
      })
    }
    
    const sendPDF = async (pdf) => {
      if (!sendEmail) {
        sendEmail = require('../../utils/sendgrid').sendEmail
      }
      
      sendEmail({ /* config for sending the mail */})
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems ok at first sight. What about adding a catch block to check if there is any issue?

Comment: No issues are caught with a try catch, the code performs without errors. My theory based on delaying the res.status.send() is that CF termination cancels the White process to firestore even if the update promise is resolved. A delay down to 50ms seems to provide enough time to finalize the update.

Comment: Shouldn't you await `sendEmail()` (at the bottom) ?

Comment: In addition, try adding a `return` at the end of `savePDF`, e.g. `const savePDF = async (refs, pdf) => {... return null;}`

Comment: sendMail() actuality gets send before savePDF finishes, thus working as intended for now. I did try returning the last .update() instead of await, same result. I will however try with an explicit null return after .update() later today to check if that somehow triggers something.

Comment: Just tried the explicit null return at the end of `savePDF` which unfortunately did not have an effect.